# Is there a method for computing optical flow for non-rigid bodies (ie. objects that are expanding/shrinking)?

Tags: graphics, machine-learning, computer-vision, opticalflow

I am working with optical flow methods for trying to interpolate the motion between two frames in which an object is shrinking. Methods such as Farneback and Lucas-Kanade seem to be constrained to affine transformations and have same-intensity assumptions. Has there been a method developed that deals with objects that change in size?

Thanks!

Comment: Hum, affine includes scale change. Perhaps posting sample images/videos would get you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dense optical flow method. Theses methods rely on the intensity assumption are more robust against violation. What you are looking for is an optical flow method that better preserves motion discontinuities of in the flow field. In additions, method based on feature matching such as the Patchmatch method better deal with scale changes. More recent methods do that to e.g. the Flowfields method. I would refer to the MPI-SINTEL benchmark webpage:

http://sintel.is.tue.mpg.de/results

, where you can find other usefill links to sourecode of more recent approaches.